# Python: Merging list elements into one

Tags: python, arrays, concatenation

I was wondering if there are any methods in Python to join the elements of a list into one element. Currently I have something like:

```
Test = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
print Test[0]
(1, 2, 3)
print Test[1]
(4, 5, 6)
```

I want this:

```
Test = [(1, 2, 3), (4 ,5, 6)]
print Test[0]
(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)
```

I then want to be able to transfer the contents of Test[0] and transfer it to a numpy array such that:

```
array = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), ...]
array[0] = (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)
array[1] = (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)
```

I tried converting to a string and concatenating, but it converts *everything* in the list (i.e., brackets and all) into chars. Any suggestions?

EDIT1: I forgot to mention that I will be using a large amount of data. I tried using extend(), append() and the "+" operator but doing this will run into memory issues as it seems extend, append, and + holds the growing list in memory.

EDIT2: Also note that the elements (x, y, z) are a numpy array structure.

EDIT3: There was some confusion. I don't just want to print the format (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), I need the data types to be in the numpy array fashion.

Comment: Can't you just do (1,2,3) + (4,5,6)?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I will be using a large amount of data. Please see the edit.

Comment: What do you want Test[1] to show then?

Comment: Test should be an array/list containing only one element. I.e., only Test[0] = (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)

Comment: Why use an array then if it only has one element?  Just `print Test`.  It already is a list of tuples.  Otherwise, @jamylak's answer does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
Test = [Test]
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> "Test should be an array/list containing only one element. I.e., only
>   Test[0] = (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)"

You can 'wrap' Test within another list, thus making it seem as one element (although you could also access children of that list):

```
Test = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
Test = [Test]
print Test[0] # [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
```